# Retrieve Wi-Fi information elements

Tags: windows, cmd, wifi, router

I am writing a script that scans all available wifi's and does some post-processing on them. I recently found out that you can read out Router Model and Router Name as well from the wifi signal.

At the moment I am using the command `netsh wlan show networks mode=bssid` to list the wifi's and then my script uses this output. But this output doesn't contain the Router Model or name. I found a tool [WifiInfoView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wifi_information_view.html#DownloadLinks) that displays this info but I would like to have a native cmd tool that does it as well. Is there a way to adjust the netsh command to also display this info or a different cmd program that can display this?

EDIT:
I would like an output in the form of what netsh now gives as output but can also be totally different as well. (I can easily change the parsers of my script.)
As an example ideally something like this:

Output of the netsh cmd:

```
SSID 1 : MyWiFi
    Network type            : Infrastructure
    Authentication          : WPA2-Personal
    Encryption              : CCMP
    BSSID 1                 : 00:00:00:00:00:00
         Signal             : 45%
         Radio type         : 802.11n
         Channel            : 6
         Basic rates (Mbps) : 1 2 5.5 11
         Other rates (Mbps) : 6 9 12 18 24 36 48 54
```

Would like to add something like this:

```
Router Name:            : CISCO
Router Model:           : CISCO modelX
```

Comment: Can you please give a sample of the exactly output you would expect from a command line tool?

Comment: Added an example in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked everywhere and can't seem to find a native tool that can do this. Also apparently the netsh command has no way of displaying this info.

So for now I will use WiFi Info View with the cmd:

`WifiInfoView.exe /NumberOfScans 1 /scomma output.csv /MacAddressFormat 3 /DisplayMode 1`

which gives a nice csv file with all information that I need.